# Cannot get the hidden tag value

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var x= document.getElementById("2").value;
        document.getElementById("1").innerHtml = x;
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<p hidden="hidden" id="2">This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
<p>This is a visible paragraph.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The hidden attribute is not supported in IE.</p>
    <p id="1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

in this code i have a hidden tag as you can see. I want that the javascript code read text value of the `p` tag with an id `2` and then print the same value to other `<p>` tag wiht `id="1"`. But this is not working. Earlier i even tried to use `nodeValue` but also this is not working and when i checked out in google developer tool then it was showing an error as following:

> **Cannot read property 'value/nodeValue' of null**

please **note**:

after a quick experiment i noted that after adding a event handler `<body onload="y();>"` there was no error but there was no expected result!

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. there is no innerHtml, innerHTML is the correct syntax.
2. the hidden "p" does not have a value, it is not an input field. use innerHTML for accessing it.
3. your javascript code runs before the browser knows about paragraps, so they don't exist when you want them to be accessed. put javascript after the paragraphs or run the code after the page is loaded.

this should work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p hidden="hidden" id="2">This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
    <p>This is a visible paragraph.</p>
    <p><b>Note:</b> The hidden attribute is not supported in IE.</p>
    <p id="1"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x= document.getElementById("2").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = x;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`hidden` is an `input` element `type`, not a `p` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" id="2" value="This input should be hidden." />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this (and if you try and style it also) is that classes and ID's should not start with (or include) numbers.

Rename your ID's to `one` and `two` and then update your javascript accordingly.

e.g

```
<p id="one">Some stuff</p>
```

Also `hidden` cannot be used with a `p` element as it's for `inputs` only.

You're better off using `display:none;` in `CSS`.

If you **NEED** to access it via `css` as a number, you can use

```
[id='1']{
    /*code*/ 
}
```

but your javascript still wont work.

As James has pointed out, using numbers for `ID`'s is perfectly valid in `HTML5`.

Comment: Numbers are perfectly valid for IDs in HTML5.

Comment: But javascript and css have difficulty selecting them. I' not saying you CAN'T use them, just that (for now) it's impractical to. But I'll update my answer because you have a very valid point, thank you :) @JamesDonnelly

Answer (score 0):

Don't use numbers for ID.

Try something like `<p id="hello"></p>`

Comment: Numbers are perfectly valid for IDs in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your  tag to  then you can set a CSS class with .hidden { display:none; }.

Wrap your Javascript in a function and call it when you need to or go back to your

Also as Maaz said, try not to use numbers in your ID's.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden. And as James noted several times below, IDs can start with numbers in HTML5.

Comment: But CSS has trouble with it @j08691

Comment: True, but how does that relate to this question? There's no CSS involved here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hiddenValue = document.getElementById('2').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = hiddenValue;
```

Comment: A little comment explaining what is your solution based on wouldn't harm.

Comment: The question was about getting a value from a paragraph (p element). The value-property doesn't work, but innerHTML will.